# Increase size of rCharts on Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I am doing a Shiny Dashboard using the `shinydashboard` package. As you see in the image attached, the chart done using rCharts and the HighCharts library is not using all the space of the Box. I would like to know if anyone knows how to user all the space of the box. See attached the code used:

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(rCharts)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tags$head(tags$style('.col-sm-6 {padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px ;}')),
      box(status = "primary", width = 3, showOutput("plotAtmosphere", "Highcharts")) 
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plotAtmosphere = renderChart({  
         a <- rHighcharts:::Chart$new()
          d <- data.frame(label = c("Negative", "Positive"), value = c(30, 70))
          a$title(text = "")
          # a <- hPlot(value ~ label, data = d, type = 'pie')
          a$data(x = c("Negative","Positive"), y = c(30, 70), type = "pie", name = "Amount")
          a$plotOptions(pie = list(innerSize = "90%", 
          startAngle = -90, endAngle = 90, center = list("50%", "100%"),dataLabels = list(enabled = F)))
          a$exporting(enabled = F)   
          a$chart(height = 150)   
          return(a)    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Posting partial code with > reduces the chance that someone will respond, because most people need to see the code in action. See the example below how to create a short shiny app to show the heart of the matter.

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate parameters like [size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.size) or [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size)

Comment: I updated the code so now is complete and you can use as a short shiny app. Thanks

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks, that makes the chart bigger but I am losing responsiveness of it.

Comment: Your code is not self-contained. rHighchart is not in library(), and it's anyway included in rCharts.

Comment: @aruizga catch $(windows).resize() event and then call [chart.setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize)

Comment: and...do you know how to do this with R?

Answer (score 2):

this is annoyingly complicated, but you have to pass an additional parameter to your server() fuction:

```
server <- function(input, output, session)
```

and then use one of the session variables from clientData to dynamically resize your plots:

```
output$hexchart<-renderChart2({
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type = "spline")
h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, NA), dashStyle = "longdash")
h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
h1$set(width = session$clientData$output_plot1_width) #dynamically resize with session variable
return(h1)
})
```

where plot1 is a dummy plot inserted in your ui:

```
box(width = 12, height = 450, solidHeader = FALSE, status = "primary",
              plotOutput("plot1", height = "1px"),
              showOutput("hexchart","highcharts")
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS:

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(


  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      tags$head(tags$style('.col-sm-6 {padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px ;}')),
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: seems that CSS is not enough here....I edited my post so now my code is reproducible, and I added your CSS code but still doesn't work.